# SimpleITK: apply inverse transformation

Tags: python, image-processing, registration, simpleitk, transformation-matrix

I have recently began to use SimpleITK for image registration. For my current project I need to register an X-Ray image and a CT image, and then apply the inverse matrix on a ROI mask traced on the X-Ray image.

I got the inverse matrix with this line:

```
inverse_transform = final_transform.GetInverse()
```

How can I apply the transform to the ROI mask?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Welcome to SimpleITK!

Assuming your X-ray is the fixed image in the registration (CT is the moving) then the result of the registration is a transformation mapping points from the X-ray to the CT. All you need to do is re-sample your ROI mask image onto the CT using the inverse transformation.

`transformed_labels = sitk.Resample(xray_roi_mask,
                                   ct_image,
                                   inverse_transform, 
                                   sitk.sitkNearestNeighbor,
                                   0.0, #out of bounds pixel color
                                   xray_roi_mask.GetPixelID())`

The last cell of [this  Jupyter notebook](https://github.com/InsightSoftwareConsortium/SimpleITK-Notebooks/blob/master/Python/65_Registration_FFD.ipynb) does this.

Two additional comments:

1. Not sure what you mean by X-ray to CT registration. This is a 2D/3D registration which is currently not supported by SimpleITK, so I am assuming that your are either doing 2D/2D or 3D/3D registration.
2. As you are new to SimpleITK I would recommend looking at our [main Jupyter notebook repository](https://github.com/InsightSoftwareConsortium/SimpleITK-Notebooks) or the more concise [IEEE ISBI'18 tutorial](https://github.com/SimpleITK/ISBI2018_TUTORIAL) to familiarize yourself with the toolkit.

Comment: Thank you! It is exactly what I need to do. I'm performing a 3D/3D registration. I used 'X-ray' improperly, I have an image from an X-ray intraoperative system. And thanks for the links.